# Binomial Probablity

Tags: probability, statistics

A multiple choice test has 40 questions. Each question has five possible answers of which one is correct. Assuming that an individual has studied and has a 70% chance of answering a question correctly, what is the expected number of correct answers?

Comment: Linearity of expectation gives the obvious answer

Answer (score 0):

The expected number of correct answers is simply $40*0.7=28$.

In general, we have $E(X)=np$

Comment: $n$ stands for the number of trials , $p$ for the probability of success.

Comment: The number of possible answers does not play any role.